# Probably broken disk – any ideas?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure

Problem is following:
I've got a disk that wasn't detected by the Panasonic TV it was formatted for.
I've tried some stuff without promising results (see below). Any ideas what else could be tried before giving up?

Information I got from the disk:

`lsusb`:

```
ID 152d:2509 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS539 SuperSpeed SATA II 3.0G Bridge
```

`lshw`:

```
description: SCSI Disk
physical id: 0.0.0
bus info: scsi@10:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/sdb
configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512`
```

`dmesg`:

```
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

What I have tried yet:

- `scalpel` – no results;
- `dd` – finished in no-time, size of copy 0 (tried with different block sizes, even though that shouldn't make a difference when not even single bits can be read);
- `gparted` – sdb not selectable;
- `fdisk` – cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory;
- connecting directly as SATA: e.g. `gparted` throws I/O error.

I'm out of hope to do anything with my knowledge but don't want to give up before asking the community ;)
So, does anybody have a new idea that could work?

---

Additional Info:
the disk is a Seagate Barracuda 7200.12 1TB (ST31000524AS).

Comment: Can you actually read *anything*? E.g., what does `hexdump -C /dev/sdb' show (as root)? Any errors in syslog while reading? The disk has a USB-to-SATA bridge. In case the bridge is broken, what happens if you take it out of the enclosure, and connect it directly to SATA?

Comment: hexdump also gives no output, for errors see dmesg output in the Question

Comment: Then it can't read. The interesting question: Are there errors? What errors?

Comment: What is the SMART status of the disk? you can use smartmon or palimpsest (gnome-disks) to read smart stats.

Comment: @dirkt: connecting it directly as SATA gives minor improvements (e.g. size is shown) however mounting or using dd isn't possible nevertheless

Comment: @FrankThomas: SMART is said to be not supported in gnome-disks

Comment: The Seagate-Tools also aren't able to detect the disk. So probably it's really broken without a chance. Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: BTW, randomly trying stuff is not how you debug a harddisk problem. You issue commands via SATA (e.g. in the forms of other tools that read the disk), and watch the response in the logs, and *look at the error messages*. Because those tell you what is wrong. What "is shown" (size) doesn't really give you information. For SMART, use `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` as root, and not gnome-disks or such crap.